# C# Resize bitmap image before decoder operations

Tags: c#, xaml, ocr

I'm attempting to create a small OCR application where I can select words.  I have already implemented this using the Microsoft example:

```
protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    // Load image from install folder.
    var file = await Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync("photo.png");
    using (var stream = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read))
    {
        // Create image decoder.
        var decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(stream);

        // Load bitmap.
        var bitmap = await decoder.GetSoftwareBitmapAsync();

        // Extract text from image.
        OcrResult result = await ocrEngine.RecognizeAsync(bitmap);

        // Display recognized text.
        OcrText.Text = result.Text;
    }
}
```

However, I want the loaded image to fit to the screen, I do this by simply creating a BitmapImage, setting its source to the stream and applying the source of an Image element to the bitmap.  This problem with this, is that coords of the OCR words are not aligned to the image, as I presume the bitmap created from the decoder uses the original image size.  How can I rectify this issue, so that the size of the image the OCR engine uses is the same as Image element?

My code to get the image, and to get an OCR result from:

```
// Create a stream from the picked file
IRandomAccessStream stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);

// Create a bitmap from the stream
BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
bitmap.SetSource(stream);

this.imgDisplay.Source = bitmap;

// Create the decoder from the stream
var decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(stream);

// Get the SoftwareBitmap representation of the file
SoftwareBitmap sBitmap = await decoder.GetSoftwareBitmapAsync();    

mOcrResult = await mOcrEngine.RecognizeAsync(sBitmap);
```

Comment: you haven't provide the code that fits the loaded image to the screen, that is the key to repro your issue.

Comment: It's just setting the source of a XAML Image control to the bitmap of a picked file.  The problem is, is that since the image created from the stream of the picked file is resized to the screen, the coordinates of the words are misaligned, as the OCR engine uses the stream which hasnt been resized.  I wanted to know if there was a way to also resize the stream before using the OCR engine.

Comment: what if you change the order of you code, first get the OCR result, then set the show the image in `imgDisplay`?  can it work correctly?

Comment: No.  Since the image is resized, the OCR engine should have the same sized image to work from, so that the words are technically in the same place.